# Couldnot import module revit python wrapper (rpw) on revitpythonshell2018

Tags: github, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I want to use revit python wrapper with revitpythonshell. I cloned revit python wrapper repo from https://github.com/gtalarico/revitpythonwrapper onto my desktop. Then what should i do so that revitpythonshell can have access to this module? All rpw doc (https://revitpythonwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) saying is to clone revitpythonshell repo. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you also do the second step: "Add the the repository directory to RevitPythonShell’s search path"?